# i want to compile .py to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

i want to compile .py to .exe. But when i do so the exe files is too big. Is there a solution??
i want the exe to be a smaller
i know that  python was not meant to be compiled, executables made from python are bound to be large
, but the problem is i have learnt python like 3 years, and now i want to make apps/games for windows. i can't just install python on every device??

i want to make it small
i learnt that there is something called executable-packing??
using tools like crinkler
how can we do that with python
with pyinstaller or cx_freeze

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce cx\_Freeze compiled Python executable size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259914/how-to-reduce-cx-freeze-compiled-python-executable-size)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 is supported by PyInstaller.

Open a cmd window in your Python folder (open a command window and use cd or while holding shift, right click it on Windows Explorer and choose 'Open command window here'). Then just enter

pip install pyinstaller
And that's it.

The simplest way to use it is by entering on your command prompt

pyinstaller file_name.py
For more details on how to use it, take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: @Jony Varghese thanks for your help, but kindly read the question more carefully. i know how to convert it, but the problem is that the file is very large. is there a way i can make it smaller(compress it but not with zip)